# Neural network errors don't change

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a model using TensorFlow. I was getting weird results when looking at my model performance. I built two models to classify images, one using a CNN and the other using a traditional ANN. Below is the code setup for each of them.

```
#CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((20, 60, 3)))

#model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), (2, 2), activation='elu'))
#model.add(Conv2D(64, (4, 4), (2, 2), activation='elu'))
#model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'elu'))
#model.add(Dense(25, activation = 'elu'))
#model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
#model.add(Dense(1))

opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0009, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(Adam(lr = 0.0001), loss='mse', metrics = ['mae'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), batch_size= 32)


#ANN model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((20, 60, 3)))

#model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
#model.add(Dense(1))

opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0009, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(Adam(lr = 0.0001), loss='mse', metrics = ['mae'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), batch_size= 32)
```

However, the problem is that I am getting nearly identical loss, and mean absolute error metrics using both of these models, when I am expecting the mae to be MUCH higher for the 2nd model. Does anyone know why this is happening? Could it be something wrong with my input data?

P.S. This network is trying to do regression to predict steering angle for a self-driving rc car from a image

**EDIT:**

- Here is the ending error with the **CNN**:
  `Epoch 20/20 113/113 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0382 - mae: 0.1582 - val_loss: 0.0454 - val_mae: 0.1727 dict_keys(['loss', 'mae', 'val_loss', 'val_mae'])`
- Here is the ending error with the **ANN**:
  `Epoch 20/20 113/113 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0789 - mae: 0.2187 - val_loss: 0.0854 - val_mae: 0.2300 dict_keys(['loss', 'mae', 'val_loss', 'val_mae'])`

Comment: How could we possibly answer this without your training data?

Comment: @gobrewers14 I was just wanting to know of any possible cause of this issue. The reason I didn't put up my training data was mainly because I don't know how to, since I am still pretty new the site, but if anyone can think of any possible causes for me to debug, I would appreciate that. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is from your training data, try using another data and check the results again